# Hide divider underneath View.GONE element

Tags: android

The problem that I'm facing is that I have 3 buttons underneath each other. One of them is always visible. The other two might get a visibility value of View.GONE. Between these buttons are dividers. As the View.GONE-elements are still inside the layout, the dividers are still visible even though the elements are hidden. Is there a way to hide the dividers underneath the hidden buttons without removing the buttons from the parent element? 
Thanks!

```
      <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/a"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:showDividers="middle">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/c"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/d"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post your xml code

Answer (score -1):

Set the dividers visibility to GONE as well.  Or put them in a linear layout with the buttons, and make the entire layout GONE.